# ActiveX html control not calling code

Tags: javascript, c++, activex, windows-ce

I have an ActiveX HTML Object as defined here:

```
<object id="HSMBTPrintX1" width="350" height="350"
   classid="CLSID:68d05400-18a6-4b39-b3ff-a17d77c1eddf" codebase=".\HSMBTPrintX.ocx">
```

And a button:

```
<input type="button" name="Print" value="Print" onclick="PassParameter()" />
```

This button calls some javascript defined above the button and control:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function PassParameter() {
            if (StringInput.value != " ") {
                alert('1 - ' + HSMBTPrintX1);
                HSMBTPrintX1.InputParameter = StringInput.value;
                alert('2 - ' + StringInput.value);
                var temp = HSMBTPrintX1.PrintLabel();
                alert('3 -' + temp);
            }
    }
</script>
```

My PrintLabel C++ code method, here:

```
char* CHSMBTPrintXCtrl::PrintLabel(void)
{
    return "temp";
    //AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState());

    // TODO: Add your dispatch handler code here
    TCHAR g_szComPort[16];
    char szout[512];
    HANDLE hCom;
    TCHAR comPort[16];
    unsigned long bytesWritten;
    int counter;
    AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState());
    if (!FindBluetoothPort(g_szComPort))
    return "minus two";
    hCom = CreateFile(comPort,GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE,0,0,OPEN_EXISTING,0,0);
    if (hCom == NULL)
    return "minus one";
    CStringA charstr(m_InputParameter);
    // Create text to send to printer
    strcpy(szout, "^XA\n");
    strcat(szout, "^PRC ^LH0,0 ^LL203 ^PW406 ^MD5 ^MFF,F ^MMT ^MNM ^CF0,20,12 ^XB\n");
    strcat(szout, "^FO20,05 ^AFN ^FV MASTER PACK ^FS\n");
    strcat(szout, "^XZ");

    // Write file to Bluetooth COM port
    if(WriteFile(hCom,szout,256,&bytesWritten,NULL)==0)
    {
        return "one";
    }
    return "two";
    FireLabelPrinted();
}
```

And as you can see, (just for testing), as soon as the function is called it returns some text.  I attempt to output this text in a javascript alert.

The issue is, the "temp" javascript variable outputs as "undefined"... so i'm assuming the PrintLabel function never even gets called.

---

For some background information (which may or may not help in a conclusion), i am using VS2008, creating a Visual C++ Smart Device project.  The solution also has a Smart Device CAB Project added on.  The entire solution is then built;  I copy the .CAB, .INF, .OCX and .HTML files to a single folder on a handheld device running Windows CE.

Additionally, I am not very familiar with C++... nor ActiveX.  Any help is appreciated!!

If i need to provide more information, just point me in a direction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue was with my HTML object... i now have the version number, and all caps for the class id:

```
<object id="HSMBTPrintX1" width="350" height="350"
                    classid="CLSID:68D05400-18A6-4B39-B3FF-A17D77C1EDDF"
                    codebase=".\HSMBTPrintX.ocx#1,0,0,1">
```

everything is working fine now.

Answer (score 2):

In order to expose a new method to javascript you need to add it to your IDL file; in addition, you won't be able to return a char* from an ActiveX control, you'll need to return a BSTR. In your case, the char* is released when the function goes out of scope and becomes invalid anyway.

What is actually occurring is that javascript checks for a PrintLabel method on the COM interface, doesn't find one, and just defaults to undefined.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @Taxilian's comments, you also *must* implement [IObjectSafety](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768224%28VS.85%29.aspx) or the browser won't be able to access the object (this is one of the more common omissions for CE browser-targeted controls).